# Device credentials in net maui

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I want to add a security check on my app (iOS,Android and Windows). I would like to use the device credentials for login.
If user has biometric check in his phone, I can use 'Plugin.Fingerprint' to check the credential but I don't know how can I check if the user has the pin or password.

How can I do this in net maui?

Comment: all Biometric does is tell you is validate that the person holding the phone is authorized to have access to the phone.  Any further login or auth mechanism is up to you to implement

Comment: But if the person doesn't have biometric control how can I check the pin or password? I don't want to create any more logins, I wanna use the device credentials.

Comment: *"how can I check the pin or password?"* You can't force user to enter those again. (And if you could, that would confuse users. The device's pin/password is for enabling the device. Not individual apps.)

Comment: Sorry but I disagree, some apps I use ask me for my device credentials to access sensitive content. I can choose whether to use biometric data or pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, alternatively, you can set the `AllowAlternativeAuthentication` to `true` if you want it to fall back to using a pin or password. Then the `FallbackTitle` like "**Use Password**" or “**Use PIN**”.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration
("Login using biometrics", "Confirm login with your biometrics")
{
    FallbackTitle = "Use PIN",
    AllowAlternativeAuthentication = true,
};
```

Besides, this is their [Source repository](https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint), you could create a new issue for further assistance if needed.